# SMOTE is not available in WEKA

Tags: weka

8.0 version but I was unable to find the SMOTE package is available there. Can someone let me know what I'm missing here, and why I can't see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm seeing the version number of the SMOTE package for Weka as 1.0.3, not 8.

Use the Package Manager to add this into Weka.

It will show up in the Preprocess tab, as a supervised instance filter.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Close all weka tabs except first page(Weka GUI Chooser)
2. Click tools > Package Manager
3. Search for SMOTE and click install.
4. Close Package Manager.
   Now you can access SMOTE to explorer > Filter(choose) > supervised > instance > SMOTE.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for SMOTE to be installed.

Here is the link how to teach it. 
https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/data-mining-with-weka/7/steps/657988

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)